# Only show alert on blur and if no selection from dropdown was made

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, vue.js

I use Google Maps Places to autocomplete my input. I am trying to somewhat force the user to select an address from the populated drowdowns, because I want to work with that selected place.

The issue I have though, is that I want to enable the user to enter an address that might not be populated by Google, so on blur I would like to show an alert asking the user if the address is correct.

The issue here is that even when I select from the dropdown, it will show the alert, because the input will blur out.

How can I make sure that the alert is only shown if no place from Google was selected and if it blurs?

```
<template>
    <input
           type="text"
           name="address"
           @blur="onBlur()"
    />
</template>

<script>
//...
mounted: function() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById(this.id),
        this.options
    );

    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', (blur) => {
        console.log('place changed ');
        let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.setAddress(place);
    });
},

methods: {
    onBlur() {
        this.isThisYourAddress();
    },

    isThisYourAddress() {
        return swal('test');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: [codepen.io/EbqZwx](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbqZwx) If anyone wants a pen to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is: use `$refs` to save the input value each time it is set. On blur, check whether the value has changed from the last one saved. The trick is to ensure that the place-change operation saves the new value before the on-blur tests it. I put in a little time delay for that. You could probably put in a better gatekeeper.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lastSelected: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('auto'),
        this.options
    );

    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', (blur) => {
        var  place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.lastSelected = this.$refs.input.value;
        console.log('place changed ', this.lastSelected);
        this.setAddress(place);
    });
  },
  methods: {
      onBlur() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const v = this.$refs.input.value;
          if (v !== this.lastSelected) {
            this.lastSelected = v;
            this.isThisYourAddress();
          }
        }, 100);
      },

      isThisYourAddress() {
        return 'something'
      }
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXVRaY?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks, Roy! Because it is external request being made to Google, could you think of a workaround rather then to using setTimeout? For the time being it should work, but just wondering.

Comment: Also, it seems that even with your snippet isThisYourAddress() will get called, even when selecting via the dropdown. I can assume though that the address is correct in that case, hence it should not show. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my code excerpt above (but not the codepen) so that `isThisYourAddress` is only called after the testing is done.

Comment: After looking at the API for a bit, I don't see a better alternative to `setTimeout` for this. :(